# Nested EJS Template Loops

Tags: node.js, templates, ejs

I'm trying to access a nested array in EJS template. On my backend I'm rendering out this, 'lists' is an array of business and userId is the user _id from the session.

```
res.render('listOfBusinesses', {lists:business, userId:loggedUserID});
```

On the front-end I'm looping through lists and getting the correct property values, however one property is an array of followers _ids which I need to cross check with the userId to give either a follow button or an unfollow button.

The front-end looks like this:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) { %>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 panel">
     <a href="/busProfileFromUser?busId=<%= lists[i]._id %>">
      <img src="<%= lists[i].imgpath %>" class="img-responsive follow-img" />
     </a> 
  </div>
```

The above works as expected but the property `lists[i].followers` is an array that I need to loop through again but just can't get the syntax correct.

I'm thinking along these lines:

```
for (var i = 0; i< lists[i].followers.length; i++){

  if (list[i] == userId) {
    <button>Follow</button>
  } else {
    <button>Unfollow</button>
  }
}
```

Extremely gratefully for any advice!!

Almost have this solved, was stuck for a while but part the problem was the variable passed on render was used in the conditional statement, which was checking for an object id being equal to a string. So I called toString() to make sure they were bout strings. It is now returning the correct button, however it's only returning one button, and not displaying anything for the rest of the list of businesses.
Can anyone shed any light on why the other buttons are not displaying

```
        <% for (var j = 0; j < lists[i].followers.length; j++) {%>

            <% if (lists[i].followers[j].toString() == userId.toString())           { %>
              <button>Unfollow</button>

              <% } else { %>
                <button>FOLLOW</button>
              <% } %>

        <% } %>
```

Answer (score 7):

Nested loops and conditionals are completely supported by EJS. Once you are traversing a list of something, you can take another iteration variable and make a nested loop.

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {%>
  <a href="/busProfileFromUser?busId=<%= lists[i]._id %>">
    <img src="<%= lists[i].imgpath %>" class="img-responsive follow-img" />
  </a>

  <!-- Nested loop below --> 
  <% for (var j = 0; j < lists[i].followers.length; j++) {%>
    <li>
      <% if (lists[i].followers[j] == userId) { %>
        <button>Follow</button>
      <% } else { %>
        <button>Unfollow</button>
      <% } %>
    </li>
  <% } %>

<% } %>
```

Comment: Thank you this looks like the syntax I need, and it almost works, for some reason it's not rendering the second condition at all. I have 5 dummy businesses set up of which the user follows 2, and 2 buttons are rendering out but not the others.

Comment: Sounds like that issue is a bit more specific, and depends on the rendered model. I can only help you further if I get to see that data, because on the EJS side it should work fine.

Comment: Try updating your question with that data, the expected result and the outcome.

Comment: found another issue in this code, the userId in the if statement - it's not reading it properly, should the syntax change in order to read a variable in the conditional statement ?

Comment: That would not pose a problem, since you added `userId` to the renderer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `i` to something else, as it's overwriting the `i` in the outer scoped loop.

You're also not accessing the `followers` property.

Your inner loop should look like this:

```
<% for (var j = 0; j < lists[i].followers.length; j++) { %>
  <% if (list[i].followers[j] == userId) { %>
    <button>Follow</button>
  <% } else { %>
    <button>Unfollow</button>
  <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Controller Side 
     var sidebarnavigation = req.session["sidebarnavigation"];
      res.render(view_path, {
        TODAY_DATE: TODAY_DATE,
        base_URL: base_URL,
        navigations: sidebarnavigation,
      });
    
    
    Nested Loops In EJS
    <body class="mini-sidebar">
        <div class="main-wrapper">
          **<!-- sidebar menu -->
          <%-include("../partials/common_sidebar_nav",{"navigations":navigations})%>**
        </div>
//Partial Section

        <div id="sidebar-menu" class="sidebar" style="cursor: pointer;">
          <div class="sidebar-inner slimscroll">
              <div id="sidebar-menu1" class="sidebar-menu">
                  <ul>            
                    <% navigations.forEach(function(menu){%>                
                            <li class="menu-title"><%= menu.role_name %><span></li>
                                <% menu.main_menu.forEach(function(main_menu){ %>
                                    <li class="submenu">
                                        <a href="#">                                    
                                            <span><%= main_menu.nav_display_name %> </span><span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                                        </a>                                
                                        <ul style="display: none;">
                                            <% main_menu.sub_menu.forEach(function(sub_menu){ %>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a>
                                                        <i class="la la-minus"></i>&nbsp; <%= sub_menu.nav_display_name %>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            <%})%>                                    
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                <%})%>
                    <%})%>
                    
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Instead of only posting some code, you should also explain how this is supposed to answer the question.